# How to implement a MainViewModel in a WPF App?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need help understanding the implementation of a `MainViewModel` in a WPF App.

For instance, let's say I have a Window named *Tools* which is made of several `ViewModels`.
How can I set the DataContext of that Window to a `MainViewModel` which represents all my `ViewModels`? Is the DataContext of one element, let's say a ListBox, going to be bound to its corresponding `ViewModel` attribute in the `MainViewModel` ?

Comment: Tools is a panel within mainwindow? In which case it probably should be a usercontrol rather than window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options here:

1. Override the `OnStartup` method in the `App` class, where you will create a window instance and set the `DataContext` there.

```
protected override OnStartup(/*Some args here*/)
{
    base.OnStartUp(/*Some args here*/);

    var mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    var mainWindow = new MainWindow
    {
        DataContext = mainWindowViewModel
    };

    MainWindow = mainWindow;
    MainWindow.Show();
}
```

Don't forget to remove the `StartupUri` attribute in the `App.xaml` file and set the `ShutdownMode=OnMainWindowClose` there.

2. Create the `MainWindowViewModel` instance in the window constructor.

```
public class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel()
    }
}
```

To sum up - the first approach is better in my opinion because You can resolve all view-model dependencies within the `App` class and separate that logic from the view-model itself.

> Is the DataContext of one element, let's say a ListBox, going to be bound to its corresponding `ViewModel` attribute in the `MainViewModel`?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the `MainWindowViewModel` is just going to create instances of each `ViewModel` (singletons or not )?

Comment: @pelishen well, it is up to you how you would create those instances, for example, you could pass the `IServiceProvider` into the main view-model and create instances on demand. But yes, as long as you use the main window - it's datacontext would be alive as well as the instances within.